# How to save input value to database magento2

Tags: magento2, database, newsletter, setup-script

I am absolutely new in magento. I have made new input called **'name'** under email input in

> app/design/frontend/NewVendor/NewTheme/Magento_Newsletter/templates/subscribe.phtml

```
<div class="block newsletter">
<div class="title"><strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Newsletter')) ?></strong></div>
<div class="content">
    <form class="form subscribe"
        novalidate
        action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getFormActionUrl()) ?>"
        method="post"
        data-mage-init='{"validation": {"errorClass": "mage-error"}}'
        id="newsletter-validate-detail">
        <div class="field newsletter">
            <label class="label" for="newsletter"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Sign Up for Our Newsletter:')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="email" type="email" id="newsletter"
                       placeholder="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Enter your email address')) ?>"
                       data-mage-init='{"mage/trim-input":{}}'
                       data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
                <input name="name" placeholder="Name"/>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="actions">
            <button class="action subscribe primary" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Subscribe')) ?>" type="submit">
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Subscribe')) ?></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I have made a new column in **newsletter_subscriber** table in

> app/code/Mag/Newsletter/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php

```
class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
```

{

```
public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $setup->startSetup();
    if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '0.0.2', '<')) {
        $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $setup->getTable('newsletter_subscriber'),
            'name',
            [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'length' => 50,
                'nullable' => false,
                'default' => '',
                'comment' => 'Name'
            ]
        );
    }
    $setup->endSetup();
}
```

}

And this is my controller in

> app/code/Mag/Newsletter/Controller/Subscriber/NewAction.php

```
<?php
namespace Magebit\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber;

class NewAction extends 
\Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber\NewAction
{
    public function execute() {
        $name = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        var_dump($name);exit;
    }
}
```

For now controller var_dump's input value.

What I want to achieve is to save input value into **"name"** column in **'newsletter_subscriber'** table.

Can't get it right.
What should I do next?

Comment: It might be usefull to set the new field as nullable if you have old data in your table. With a nullable field the proposed first approach would work. With a not nullable field please use the second approach in my answer and implement the `subscribe($email, $name)` method. Please let me know if this works for you or if you need further help

Comment: Yes, thank you, it helped!
I am pretty sure, that I will have a lot of questions in nearest future!

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/344840/how-to-save-input-value-to-database-from-custom-newsletter-magento2 please see the my question and help me if u can plaese

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to implement the logic in your controller, you have to copy the `execute()` method from the original, inherited controller and load the subscriber object after it was created, add your attribute and save the object. For this you have to add the following lines right after the `subscribe()` method has been called:

```
$status = (int) $this->_subscriberFactory->create()->subscribe($email);
//your code starts here...
$newSubscriber = $this->_subscriberFactory->create()->loadByEmail($email);
$newSubscriber->setName($name);
$newSubscriber->save();
```

I hope that helps.
Anyway there are other possibilities to do this, for example creating a new method `subscribe($email, $name)` in the subscriber object and call that from your controller. With that approach you don't need to load the subscriber in the controller after creation, but you have to overwrite the subscriber model.